# Mobile Web Audience Network with Cordova/Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I implemented Facebook's new mobile web native ads in an ionic app, and everything works perfectly locally.

However when I run the app on an IOS device, the ads won't load. Anyone knows why?

I'm suspecting it has to do with the fact that the app itself isn't making the call from a domain, so Facebook is blocking it, but the problem is i'm not getting any errors that can guide me.

Comment: No errors on console using safari inspect? Is it possible to load the project in github for testing in device locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook ads are not working for TestFlight. If you download the app from AppStore then the ads will be shown correctly. Try downloading the App from AppStore not TestFlight